# What's the difference between these JSON Perl modules?

Tags: json, perl

What's the difference between the Perl JSON modules below?

I have come across [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-PP-2.27400/lib/JSON/PP.pm) and [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm).  The documentation of [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-PP-2.27400/lib/JSON/PP.pm) says it is compatible with [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm). What does that mean?

I am not sure what the difference between them are, let alone which of them to use. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Compatible in this context means that both modules are giving the same results and have the same function names. The underlying implementation is different though...

Comment: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-7/ is probably worth reading.

Answer (score 14):

Perl modules sometimes have different implementations. The `::PP` suffix is for the Pure Perl implementation (i.e. for portability), the `::XS` suffix is for the C-based implementation (i.e. for speed), and `JSON` is just the top-level module itself (i.e. the one you actually use).

As noted by @Quentin, [this site](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-7/) has a good description of them. To quote:

> #### JSON
>
> JSON.pm is a wrapper around `JSON::PP` and `JSON::XS` - it also does a bunch of moderately crazy things for compatibility reasons, including extra shim code for very old perls [...]
>
> #### JSON::PP
>
> This is the standard pure perl implementation, and if you're not performance dependent, there's nothing wrong with using it directly [...]
>
> #### JSON::XS
>
> Ridiculously fast JSON implementation in C. Absolutely wonderful [...]

As you can see, just installing the top-level `JSON` module should do it for you. The part about compatibility just means that they both do the same thing, i.e. you should get the same output from both.

I installed the Perl `JSON` module a few years ago on a RHEL server I managed and it was a really straightforward process: just install (or build) the module from the [CPAN site](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) and you're done.

Installing should be a simple case of either using the OS package manager (if in GNU/Linux), using the `cpan` utility, or building from source. The OS package manager is recommended, as it helps keep things updated automatically.

To verify that it's installed, just try the following command from the terminal (assuming GNU/Linux):

```
$ perl -e 'use JSON;'
```

If it doesn't complain, then you should be good to go. If you get errors, then you should get ready to go in an adventure.

Comment: I prefer `perl -MJSON\ 999` (with a backslash and a space) as that gives the version you have, or complains.

Comment: @simbabque: I hope that was not an explanation of why I received a down-vote?

Comment: No, I think your answer is very good. I merely added additional information. Don't worry about a single down vote. There just sometimes is someone who thinks an answer is not useful. Everyone can vote how they want. Don't get discouraged from that. :-)

Comment: @simbabque: No worries. I guess it's not great when you're told your answer is "not useful" but are not given a reason as to why that is the case from the down-voter's perspective. Sometimes it's something that can be easily addressed. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time they move on and will never see your comment. Nine people thought this is useful. That's pretty good. :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can install JSON module, cpan install JSON

```perl
use JSON;

my $result = from_json($json);
if($result->{field})
{
  # YOUR CODE
};
```

Comment: And that would answer this question?

Comment: @rustyx I think so. The answer is _"use JSON;"_ What's wrong with that? I use it myself in the exact way Jose showed and it works. Why the downvotes?

Comment: The question is not _how do I use JSON?_. The question is why there are various different JSON modules.

Comment: @simbabque, the question is "Which perl module should be used to decode JSON data?" JSON module. 
The best way to understand things, are examples.

Comment: The OP already knows that the JSON module exists, and from the way the question is asked it's pretty clear they know how to use it. While I agree with you that examples are great, I don't think your particular example of one function will help to clear up the confusion as to why there is a pure Perl and an XS implementation, and why their documentations say those are both compatible to each other.

Comment: Really, the answer is the function "from_json" from module JSON

Comment: I did not down-vote, but this post misses the point. The question is which module among all the options presented, all of which have `JSON` in their name, should be used. The OP is clearly confused about the wrapper/implementation distinction. While your example might be correct, it does not address the question. As already mentioned, the question is not *how* to use the module, but *which one* of the options he came across is supposed to be the correct one, especially when there're several `JSON::*` available.